# Как скрыть последующие элемент при клике

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, адаптивная-верстка, responsive

Привет мир!
Мне необходимо сделать чтобы при клике на  `<div class="gadget cats">` все последующие элементы скрывались под ним, и при нажатии появлялись обратно. 
Я написал `jQuery` код, но к сожалению он не работает, ребята подскажите как мне быть ?

Вот мой HTML:

```js
jQuery('.cats .catalog').on('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).find('ul.catalog').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gadget cats">
  <h2>Каталог</h2>
  <ul class="catalog menusm">

    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/325"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/402"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/428"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/129"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/304"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/405"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/348"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/404"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/44"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="/cat/133"></a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/143"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/153"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/146"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/151"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/180"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/181"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/178"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/179"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/185"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/208"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/126"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/315"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/82"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/244"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/247"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/142"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/197"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/340"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/414"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/416"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/415"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive"><a href="/cat/425">TRX</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
jQuery('.cats .catalog').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  jQuery(this).find('ul').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gadget cats">
  <h2>Каталог</h2>
  <ul class="catalog menusm" >
    <li class="active">
      <a href="/cat/133">click me</a>
      <ul style="display:none">
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/143">22222222</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/153">222222</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/208">222222222</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/126">1111111111</a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/315">1111111111</a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/415">1111111111</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**UPD:**
можно задать свой CSS:

```js
jQuery('.cats .catalog').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  jQuery(this).find('ul').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
.catalog ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gadget cats">
  <h2>Каталог</h2>
  <ul class="catalog menusm">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="/cat/133">click me</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/143">22222222</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/153">222222</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/208">222222222</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/126">1111111111</a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/315">1111111111</a>
    </li>
    <li class="passive">
      <a href="/cat/415">1111111111</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению `html` написан на CMS, он подтягивается через .mysql БД и PHP. Как возможно это сделать без внесений изменений в html код ?

Comment: @NukezhanMontreal можно задать свой CSS...